# Adaptor for 6-awg wire to wire receptable

Tags: electrical, receptacle, wire

I need to wire in a receptacle for a sump pump,115v, 15 amp. The run from the fuse box to the receptacle is 200' so #6-2 wire was used. The #6 wire is too thick for the terminals. What do I us to make this work??

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a 115V pump and not a 230V pump for this application?

Answer (score 1):

Wire nut a #14 or #12 pigtail to the incoming wire and screw to the receptacle. Just make sure to use the right wire nuts. A quick look at the Ideal catalog and it looks like typically these will be Blue or Blue/Gray, but check the specs to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to pigtail the #6 to #12 with wire nuts if your #6 is copper. If it's aluminum, you'll need to use different connectors, like Polaris-type insulated splices. If this is outdoors, you'll need it to be GFCI protected.